# How to extend a class method which is based on private methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, private-members

Let's say I have a class with the following structure and I wish to override one of its delegate method (or more, in general one of its public methods), but now it is based on some private methods. Is there a way to extend it or should I simply conclude that it was not designed with extensibility in mind?

MyBaseClass.h:

```
@interface MyBaseClass : UIView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> 
{

}

// some public methods

@end
```

MyBaseClass.m:

```
@interface MyBaseClass (Private)
- (void)_privateMethod1;
- (void)_privateMethod2;
@end

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

// ------ I'D LIKE TO CHANGE THE BEHAVIOR OF THIS METHOD EXTENDING MyBaseClass
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)rowIndexPath {
    [self _privateMethod1];
    [self _privateMethod2];
}

@end
```

I also need to refer to the private methods if I will actually follow through with extending the class but obviously I do not want to access to any private method.
I'm sorry if the question sounds a little bit trivial.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your private methods in a separate header MyBaseClassPrivate.h instead of in the implementation file and import that in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create a protocol in which you declare the methods that subclasses should implement? The base class would adopt that protocol; and the subclasses are responsible for their respective implementation.  The base class implementation could provide some generic functionality or just `return;`

```
@protocol MyBaseClassPrivateProtocol
- (void)_privateMethod1;
- (void)_privateMethod2;
@end

@interface MyBaseClass : UIViewController <MyBaseClassPrivateProtocol> 

@end
```

Comment: This has problems if, for example, you are building a framework and don't want people who are using it to know about MyBaseClassPrivateProtocol